# Finding an embedded TFrame

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, tframe

I have a TFrame that is Inherited from a TBaseFrame = class(TFrame)

Inside this there is an embeded TFrame with same inheritence

```
  TViewStandardMovimentoFinanceiro = class(TFrameBase)
    ViewStandardEdiMovimentoFinanceiro1: TViewStandardEdiMovimentoFinanceiro;

  TViewStandardEdiMovimentoFinanceiro = class(TFrameBase)

  TFrameBase = class(TFrame, INaharView, INaharViewAdapter)
```

The TViewStandardMovimentoFinanceiro is created with parent set to the main form (particularly to a THorzScrollBox)

From INSIDE the TViewStandardMovimentoFinanceiro  frame I tried the classical approach of using the Children list and have not found that embedded TFrame.

I have tried also using the Parent`s Children list with no success. Same thing with the Components List

What I want to do is to to locate all available TFrames so I can ask for an interface (I know how to do that)

What am I missing?

Following recommendations bellow I have implemented this code for testing:

```
    function TFrameBase.LocateControl(AControl: TControl; ADomainName: string): TControlHandler;
var
  NaharView: INaharView;
  ControlHandler: TControlHandler;
  i: integer;
begin
  result := nil;
  for i := 0 to AControl.ChildrenCount - 1 do
    if (AControl.Children[i] is TFrame) and (AControl.Children[i] <> Self) then
      if Supports((AControl.Children[i] as TFrame), INaharView, NaharView) then
      begin
        ControlHandler := NaharView.Control[ADomainName];
        if Assigned(ControlHandler) then
          exit(ControlHandler);
      end;
end;

function GetUltimateParent(Control: TControl): TControl;
begin
  if Control.Parent is TControl then
    Result := GetUltimateParent(TControl(Control.Parent))
  else
    Result := Control;
end;

function TFrameBase.GetNaharControl(ADomainName: string): TControlHandler;
var
  i: integer;
  ControlHandler: TControlHandler;
begin
  if NaharControls.ContainsKey(ADomainName) then
    Exit(NaharControls.Items[ADomainName])
  else
  begin
    ControlHandler := LocateControl(GetUltimateParent(Self), ADomainName);
    if Assigned(ControlHandler) then
      exit(ControlHandler);
  end;

  raise EViewControlDomainNameNotFound.Create(ADomainName);
end;
```

When LocateControl is executed it goes several levels to the top and from there it tries to iterate on Children List, it only contains 3 items in a form form full of controls.

Comment: Probably something in your code. In VCL, TFrame is a TWinControl descendant, so recursively iterating children from the ultimate parent (form) should find any instances. In FireMonkey, TFrame is a TControl descendant but the same principle applies.

Comment: @OndrejKelle ok, how can I get the ultimate parent so I can iterate thru the children? eventually my parent is not directly the TForm ?

Comment: Try something recursive like `function GetUltimateParent(Control: TControl): TControl; begin if Control.Parent is TControl then Result := GetUltimateParent(TControl(Control.Parent)) else Result := Control; end;`

Comment: @OndrejKelle I have implemented your suggestion and it went several levels to the top and ChildrenCount has only 3 objects. So seems something is wrong, or very different in FMX. I have posted the code on the question.

Comment: Looking for children should be recursive, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function LocateControl need to be recursive, as stated by Ondrej. Something like this

```
function TFrameBase.LocateControl(AControl: TControl; ADomainName: string): TControlHandler;
var
  NaharView: INaharView;
  ControlHandler: TControlHandler;
  i: integer;
begin
  result := nil;
  for i := 0 to AControl.ChildrenCount - 1 do
  begin
    if (AControl.Children[i] is TFrame) and (AControl.Children[i] <> Self) then
    begin
      if Supports((AControl.Children[i] as TFrame), INaharView, NaharView) then
      begin
        ControlHandler := NaharView.Control[ADomainName];
        if Assigned(ControlHandler) then
        begin
          exit(ControlHandler);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    // recursive bit
    Result := LocateControl(AControl.Children[i], ADomainName):
    if assigned( Result ) then
    begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Shure Ondrej deserves recognition, but since you posted the final solution as answer I have accepted. It worked.